# Show different form based on what image is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I've got 3 images in the screen. Each image should display a different form in the SAME POSITION in the screen and hide the other 2 forms.

Image1: When clicked show form1 and hide form2 and form 3

Image2: When clicked show form2 and hide form1 and form 3

Image3: When clicked show form3 and hide form1 and form 2

Forms should be shown at the same position. I just see a solution calling the whole page by sending a  parameter in the URL stating which form to show on the screen. I would really like to show the right form depending on what image is clicked at the moment without that.

I'm using HTML5, Bootstrap 4 and JavaScript - any suggestion using any of these languages would be perfect.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle of what you've attempted so far

Comment: JavaScript can accomplish all of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of answers to things like this, try looking around before asking a question.

Here is one of the simplest approaches you will ever see using only JS and HTML

**JavaScript**

```
const imageOne = document.getElementById('imageOne');
const imageTwo = document.getElementById('imageTwo');
const imageThree = document.getElementById('imageThree');

const formOne = document.getElementById('formOne');
const formTwo = document.getElementById('formTwo');
const formThree = document.getElementById('formThree');

imageOne.addEventListener("click", function() {
    formOne.style.display = "block";
    formTwo.style.display = "none";
    formThree.style.display = "none";
});

imageTwo.addEventListener("click", function() {
    formOne.style.display = "none";
    formTwo.style.display = "block";
    formThree.style.display = "none";
});

imageThree.addEventListener("click", function() {
    formOne.style.display = "none";
    formTwo.style.display = "none";
    formThree.style.display = "block;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<img id="imageOne" src="http://foo.bar">
<img id="imageTwo" src="http://bar.foo">
<img id="imageThree" src="http://last.image">

<div id="formOne" style="display: none">
    <form>
        ....
    </form>
</div>

<div id="formTwo" style="display: none">
    <form>
        ....
    </form>
</div>

<div id="formThree" style="display: none">
    <form>
        ....
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you need:

- the 3 images
- the 3 forms, with position absolute or fixed (so that they stay in the same position)
- a JS function attached to the click event of every image that changes the correspondet form style to `display:block` and the others to `display:none`.

Something like:

```
var form1 = document.getElementById('form1')

document.getElementById('form1').onclick = function() {
  form1.style.display = 'block'
  form2.style.display = 'none'
  form3.style.display = 'none'
}
```

For each one of your forms.

Here is a working pen I made to show how to do it.

https://codepen.io/jaimelopez18/pen/zWOEMw

---

This is all made with pure js (vanilla). You should try to learn this first and after you get a good grasp of it, I recommend taking a look at VueJS.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a simple skeleton in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pankaj_bhr/480pkge4/21/) as per your requirements, have a look at the code.

**HTML**:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="jsImgWrp">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="jsImg" data-formid="form1" />
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="jsImg"  data-formid="form2"/>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="jsImg" data-formid="form3" />
    </div>
    <div class="jsFormWrp form-wrapper">
      <div class="jsFrm form1 active">
        form 1
      </div>
       <div class="jsFrm form2">
        form 2
      </div>
       <div class="jsFrm form3">
        form 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**:

```
.form-wrapper .jsFrm {
  display:none;
  padding:10px;
  border:solid 2px #eee;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
}
.form-wrapper .jsFrm.active {
  display:block;
}
.jsImgWrp img {
  width:100px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

**Javascript**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var imgWrapper = $('.jsImgWrp');
var formWrapper = $('.jsFormWrp');
$('.jsImg', imgWrapper).on('click', function(){
  var formId = $(this).data('formid');
  $('.jsFrm').removeClass('active');
  $('.' + formId).addClass('active');
})
});
```

Hope this may help you.